# OmegaConf - how to delete a single parameter

Tags: python, fb-hydra, omegaconf

I have a code that looks something like this:

```
def generate_constraints(c):
    if c.name == 'multibodypendulum':
        con_fnc = MultiBodyPendulum(**c)
```

where c is an OmegaConf object containing a bunch of parameters. Now I would like to pass all the parameters in c except the name to the MultiBodyPendulum class (the name was used to identify the class to send the rest of the parameters to). However I have no idea how to make a copy of c without one parameter.
Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to get a dictionary from the instance using `my_dict = c.__dict__` and then remove the class from the dictionary using `pop()`

something like:

```
my_dict = c.__dict__
old_name = my_dict.pop("name", None)
con_fnc = MultiBodyPendulum(**my_dict)
```

That way you would add every parameter except for the name, if you wanted to add a different name you can add it to the new instance creation like:

```
con_fnc = MultiBodyPendulum(name="New Name", **my_dict)
```

Edit:

To conserve the OmegaConf functionality use:

```
my_dict = OmegaConf.to_container(c)
```

Comment: You solution almost worked, but it pointed me in a working direction. Rather than use c.__dict__ I needed to use:
my_dict = OmegaConf.to_container(c)
and then it worked

Comment: This is not a good solution as you are losing the OmegaConf functionality.

Comment: Edited it, so it conserves the functionality

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [`DictConfig.copy`](https://github.com/omry/omegaconf/blob/d02a0c10cbba8b01c92e1faffa995ebf2da4abe2/omegaconf/dictconfig.py#L141) to create a copy and [`del`](https://github.com/omry/omegaconf/blob/d02a0c10cbba8b01c92e1faffa995ebf2da4abe2/omegaconf/dictconfig.py#L377) to delete attributes/items from the `DictConfig` object.

```py
config: DictConfig = ...

config_copy = config.copy()
del config_copy.unwanted_parameter
pendulum = MultiBodyPendulum(**config_copy)
```

Comment: Take a look at Hydra's instantiate: https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/instantiate_objects/overview/